# infinite (horizontal) scroll with flexbox

Tags: javascript, scroll, flexbox, infinite

I'm trying to make an image display with infinite horizontal scroll using flexbox. I've successfully coded a horizontal scroll BUT, when I'm scrolling "down" (or, left to right), the scroll ends on the final image. If I then scroll back "up" (right to left), the flexboxes scroll infinitely....

Any idea how I can ensure scroll is infinite when scrolling "forwards?"

I've attached my javascript below. Let me know if I should attach anything else.

Thanks!

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZK3S.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could attach your Javascript in a code box by surrounding it with three backticks `\`\`like this\```, rather than an image